# Using Interface between 2 procedures with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Happy new year guys.

I have just a little problem with Pygame and I am wondering if you can help me resolving it.

Here's the thing : My exercice consists in an interface we need to reproduce with pygame and assign it as a procedure.

Next, we need to use the created interface in an other procedure without taking it as parameter in the second procedure.

The problem is that assigning the interface as global does not work at all and the only way I found to make it work is to return the interface from the first procedure (which is not a procedure anymore so) and use it as parameter for the second procedure.

Basically, that's not what's asked in my exercise so I should find an other way to do it.

My code is something like this :

```
def creating():
    a = 0
    pygame.init()

    red = (255,0,0)
    mySurface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,250))
    while a == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.draw.rect(mySurface,red,(35,23,48,64),0)
        pygame.display.update()


def otherprocedure():
    a = 0
    blue = (0,0,255)
    while a == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.draw.rect(mySurface,blue,(100,100,20,20),0) #I want this to appear on mySurface but it does not even if mySurface is a global variable
        pygame.display.update()

creating()
otherprocedure()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `mySurface` the interface you're talking about? Making it a global variable and assigning it a value in the first function and then referencing its value in the second function should work fine. Not sure what you mean by "assign it as a procedure" either.

Comment: Yes it is. I tried it last time by placing : global mySurface in the first function. But what should I put in the second function then ? I put nothing in it and it did not work. I thought once it was referenced anywhere in the code, we did not have to reference it elsewhere ?

Comment: You'll need to add a `global mySurface` to the second function, too. That wouldn't be necessary if you had something like a `mySurface = None` outside of both functions at the module level.

Comment: Still not working. I tried both solutions though... Looks like the second function can only use the created interface if it's a parameter...

Comment: Are the two functions in separate .py files?

Comment: No, they are in a same .py file.

Comment: You do realize, don't you, that both the functions in your question contain an infinite loop since nothing ever changes the value of `a`. This means that neither will ever return...

Comment: Actually, the first function does return    mySurface. I assume that it's thanks to the sys.exit() which passes the loop  but whatever. Our professors teached us to do it this way so that's what I am doing right now.

Comment: You can't quit `pygame` -- which is what `sys.exit()` will do -- and expect variable(s) created while it was running to persist and be usable in something that runs later (whether they are `global` or not). Instead you'll need to create some sort of file format that the first program creates and stores an interface definition in, and the second program reads and (re)create the interface from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blue rectangle doesn't ever get drawn because you're quitting your program (using `sys.exit()`) when a `QUIT` event is received in the first function. The way the code is now, it doesn't matter whether `mySurface` is global or not because the second function never runs. To make it work, you need to change the behavior of your first event loop to break without quitting. Then you can address the issue of passing the surface from one function to the other (e.g. by making it a `global` variable).

Try this:

```
def creating():
    global mySurface                # make mySurface a global variable

    a = 0
    pygame.init()

    red = (255,0,0)
    mySurface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,250))
    while a == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                a = 1               # this will stop the loop without ending the program

        pygame.draw.rect(mySurface,red,(35,23,48,64),0)
        pygame.display.update()


def otherprocedure():
    a = 0
    blue = (0,0,255)
    while a == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.draw.rect(mySurface,blue,(100,100,20,20),0)     # this will just work now
        pygame.display.update()

creating()
otherprocedure()
```

If you had more things to run after the second function, you might want to remove the `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` calls from there too, and let it return control to the calling code (which you'll probably want to have call `pygame.quit()` at some point).

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't think the sys.exit() works this way so now, you made it clear to my brain :) Problem solved !